# Answer sorting on this meta

Tags: discussion, status-review, featured, accepted-answer, sorting

I see that answers are sorted by giving priority to the "accepted" flag on this meta, unlike on the main site. While this makes sense for stuff like [tech-like] [support](/questions/tagged/support) requests, it makes a lot less sense for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) which are often policy proposals or questions on the interpretation thereof.

So, should answer-sorting order be changed on this meta too, to give priority only to votes, like it is on the main site, if it's technically feasible?

Comment: I added the [tag:featured] tag to this post (I had to removed the [tag:answers] tag to make room for it), so that more users could see it an weigh in on the discussion. I will circle back in a few weeks to assess the feedback on this post and move forward from there.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a good idea, and the answer sorting should be accepted-answer agnostic as on the main politics site. This should be technically feasible, see [this question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers):

> Site settings are per-site and child metas are also considered a "site".

It seems we will need to establish a community consensus on this [as we did for the main site](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/) (vote accordingly on this answer or add your own if you disagree). If an affirmative consensus is reached I will [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) this question for the CM's attention to implement.